# Why can i use getData('custom_column') but not getCustomColumn()?

Tags: column

This one has bugged me just enough to post this.. So imagine we are getting a row from the database on a custom table like so:

```
$row = $this->getCollection()->addFilter('quote_id', 1)->setPageSize(1)->getFirstItem();
```

This is all okay - and I can pull through the entire array using:

```
$row->getData();
```

Which produces:

```
Array ( [entry_id] => 15 [quote_id] => 1 [custom_column] => it works [created_time] => 2014-02-05 21:10:53 )
```

I can even get a single column by passing the column as a parameter:

```
$row->getData('custom_column');
```

But here comes the weird part for me - when I try to do this using the other technique - it cannot pull it through:

```
$row->getCustomColumn(); // DOESN'T WORK
```

Now this is strange seeing as I can pull through other columns:

```
$row->getEntryId(); // works - where is the logic?
```

Can anyone shed light on why this is? Or if the answer is out there please reference it by all means. Thanks

Comment: What is real name of your custom column?

Comment: Maybe getCustomColumn() is actual method of $row model.

Comment: @oleksii.svarychevskyi - the custom column is 'shop_name' as is in the table of the database

Comment: @mageUz - seems unlikely - the actual column is 'shop_name' but there is another 'best_match' - both do not work..

Comment: Is there actually data in that field for this record?

Comment: @mprototype - yes there is - `Array ( [entry_id] => 15 [quote_id] => 1 [shop_name] => my shop [best_match] => superb [created_time] => 2014-02-05 21:10:53 )`

Comment: @Marius - can you stop just tagging onto my posts - you never seem to contribute

Comment: @jesusg_forceHarris. I'm not tagging. Just editing the content to make it look better. If you don't like it, flag any of my answers or questions, select the reason 'Custom' and explain to a moderator what the problem is. They will take actions against me if needed.

Comment: @Marius - i never go to the teacher. The content that I've posted is the way that I want it so I just ask for you to respect that - you are of course free to contribute with NEW content of your own_

Comment: I will leave your content as you put it when you stop signing your posts: http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/5038/224252 and when you stop adding `**` at the end of your questions. And as far as  "going to the teacher"... The moderators are not teachers. they are here to make everything run smoothly. I really encourage you notify them whenever you see something that you think is wrong on this website.

Comment: @Marius - it is neither a tagline nor signature.. but i will not add anything onto the title if only to stop seeing your face everywhere.. you should think about learning & teaching rather than just syntax policing_

Comment: @jesusg_forceHarris. See...we can agree. If you ask questions correctly and format them the right way there is nothing to worry. I won't edit anything.

Comment: however you feel you need to fill your potential man _g

Comment: @jesusg_forceHarris what is the type `$row`?

Comment: jesusg_forceHarris: Take a look at @Marius's stats, history, and body of work here & let me know if you really think he "doesn't contribute anything".

Comment: That said, is the entity an EAV entity? Which table contains the columns in question? Have you cleared the Zend_Db schema cache?

Comment: jesus,check the link http://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/23853/what-is-the-difference-between-getdataname-and-getname/23854#23854

Comment: If you ever did resolve this, or if it ever went away mysteriously, I'm assuming table schema cache is the culprit. In any event: can't reproduce, too localized, closing.

Answer (score 1):

Probably `getCustomColumn()` is a real method of your model.

Answer (score -1):

The problem behind this is likely due to the fact that the attribute itself is not used in the product listing:

`Catalog/Attributes/Manage Attributes` and select your attribute, make sure that `Used in Product Listing` is set to yes. Then run a reindex & cache refresh and you should be able to call it like you're currently trying to do.

Comment: They're not product attributes that I am trying to get. These are custom columns in a custom table_g

Comment: my mistake, whoops.